# What is the problem with my gaussian filter code?

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, gaussianblur

The following code is supposed to be a gaussian filter, however when i compare the results with the gaussian filter function of scipy, i don't end up with the same results.
You can see that that the first image is "whiter" than the other  one (both were filtred with the same standard deviation).

my code gaussian filter
[image: my code gaussian filter]

scipy gaussian filter
[image: scipy gaussian filter]

noisy
[image: noisy]

Image difference
[image: Image difference]

```
from scipy import ndimage as nd
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, img_as_float
image = img_as_float(io.imread(r'C:\Users\Y\Downloads\MRI_clean.tif'))
gauss = np.random.normal(0,0.05,(940,934))
noisy = image + gauss
def convolution(oldimage, kernel):

    kernel_h = kernel.shape[0]

    if (len(oldimage.shape) == 3):
        image_pad = np.pad(oldimage, pad_width=(
        (kernel_h // 2, kernel_h // 2), (kernel_h // 2,kernel_h // 2), (0, 0)), mode = 'constant', constant_values = 0).astype(np.float32)
    elif (len(oldimage.shape) == 2):
        image_pad = np.pad(oldimage, pad_width=(
        (kernel_h // 2, kernel_h // 2), (kernel_h // 2, kernel_h // 2)), mode = 'constant', constant_values = 0).astype(np.float32)

    h = kernel_h // 2

    image_conv = np.zeros(image_pad.shape)

    for i in range(h, image_pad.shape[0] - h):
        for j in range(h, image_pad.shape[1] - h):
            # sum = 0
            x = image_pad[i - h:i - h + kernel_h, j - h:j - h + kernel_h]
            x = x * kernel
            image_conv[i][j] = x.sum()
    h_end = -h

    if (h == 0):
         return image_conv[h:, h:h_end]

    return image_conv[h:h_end, h:h_end]

def f(x,y,sigma):
    return (1/sqrt(2*math.pi*(sigma**2))) * np.exp(-(x**2+y**2)/(2*sigma**2))

def gaussian_kernel(size,sigma):
    kernel = np.zeros((size,size))
    n = (size - 1)/2
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            kernel[i, j] = f(i-n, j-n, sigma)
    return kernel/(np.sum(kernel))

gaussian = nd.gaussian_filter(noisy, sigma = 5)
filtred =convolution(noisy,gaussian_kernel(31, 5))
```

Comment: You need to normalize your kernel. You sample a finite portion of the Gaussian, which means the sum of samples is not going to be the same as the integral over the full Gaussian. The sum of your kernel needs to be exactly 1.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I didn't get what u want to say, isn't it normalized ? the sum of the kernel is indeed 1 since i divided by the sum of all the elements of the kernel

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn’t see that part. But then why have the normalization also in your function `f()`? The `(1/sqrt(2*math.pi*(sigma**2)))` is useless if you normalize afterwards anyway!

Comment: What is the difference you observe between the two results? Is it just discretization error or is it systematic?

Comment: The problem is that the image that i got after filtering is "whiter" than the one with the scipy function

Comment: @CrisLuengo in other terms, im not satisfied with the performance of my code for denoising

Comment: This looks like a perfectly good Gaussian filter code (albeit inefficient). I’m not sure what difference you see. What does “whiter” with the quotes mean? Maybe post the difference image?

Comment: @CrisLuengo you can see that the scipy gaussian filter image https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbC6.png, at the corners the image is totally dark, while for https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU528.png its not the case.

Comment: code in post is broken (indentation is syntax, in python). please [edit] your post and fix that

Comment: Could be a display issue. Compute the difference between the two results and add it to your post.

Comment: ok, next, use imshow/imwrite to *look at* everything, every kernel, every intermediate result. also print the kernels, look at every value. -- what's `nd`? code isn't a [mre], lacks imports.

Comment: Skimage likely does boundary extension other than padding with zeros, which could mean you get darker values at the edges, which would cause pyplot to scale the images differently for display. Look at the difference between the images.

Comment: @crisluengo i added the difference between the images,  it might be like you said because it seems like there is some white lines on the corners.

Comment: @christophRackwitz i added the lines which were missing

Comment: @Crisluengo it is like you said ! i plotted the image again after removing some rows and columns from the corners and it is looking exactly like the scipy function one, thank you sir.